# Specialized Keyword search for Google+?

Tags: discussion, search

Something I noticed is that when I put in a search for [Google+](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=Google%2B) results seems to come back on just "Google" (a much broader topic, with more noise to sort through)

Searching for [G+](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=G%2B) is a bit more fruitful since the letter G doesn't appear by itself often outside the context of G+

Would there be a way to augment/alter the search to index "Google+" as being meaningful / separate from "Google" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the plus sign (`+`) is considered punctuation and that's dropped by the site search.

Even wrapping it in quotes (e.g. `"google+"`) won't really help.

Alternatively, search through posts tagged [google-plus](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus) which should narrow your field to the relevant posts.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda thought that was the issue, but was hoping there might have been a way to put in an exception or something. Tags are indeed useful, but only effective if the questions are tagged :)